# How to debug C project by putting any tool/library or other

Tags: c, debugging, logging, makefile, project

I have a project, which has number of files, and a makefile. By using `make` command. I make a executable file, and then put in `/usr/local/bin`. and that is act as a utility.

Till now everything is fine, but that utility has some problem, that is not expected from the utility,
Now I have to debug that code, I have to detect where the problem is.

So for that I think that, I have to make the log at some points. But the code is big.

So. can you tell me how can I perform above task? Help me with some solutions.

I think some library, Debugger is suitable for the same, but I don't know exactly what that tool is?

Help me in the same. Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind reply

Comment: The GNU Debugger is likely to help you out here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Answer (score 1):

you can use GDB as the debugger and put breakpoints and trace the problem. Valgrind tool to check if any memory leaks are there in code.

Comment: Can you tell me any good link, that clears this tool, and helpful in implementation.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/ also you can check http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/ for gdb.

Comment: for valgrind you can check this  : http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/

Answer (score 0):

A good idea would be to write tests. This way every time you compile your code performs a series of self-tests to ensure that everything is working the way you expect. You should have tests for every unit of your code, i.e. every function, and then tests for each subsystem, and then tests for the system as a whole. There are several C libraries which will help you to structure and organize your tests. Just search for "C unit test library."

This target is typically referred to as `make check` or `make test`.

This approach will not only ensure that your system is more reliable and fault tolerant, it will also expose bugs in new features before they are added.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need GNU debugger (gdb). Please pay attention this debugger has ability not only to start program to debug but to attach to running process.

Also if this area is new for you you should understand how to compile your own program with debug information which will make debugging more simple. [This](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) should help.